# How the xor sum algorithm is connected with or?

Tags: algorithms

I was searching for a solution to the problem:
*For a given array of numbers find the sum of xor of all possible subsets. Here xor of a subset is the value comes from xoring all the elements of that subset*

[Answer of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712487/finding-xor-of-all-subsets)  gives a solution. But didn't understand how the `or` comes in the solution [see the last line of the accepted answer].

Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you follow through the example using the set $\{1,4,5\}$.  There are eight subsets.  Four of them have their XOR odd, so the $2^0$ bit is set and four have their XOR even, so the $2^0$ bit is cleared. When we add these up, we get $2^{3-1}$ times the value of the bit.  None of the subsets have the $2^1$ bit set in their XOR because none of the original numbers have their $2^1$ bit set.  The bitwise OR you are asking about is saying to find all the bits that are set in at least one of the original numbers.  For our set $\{1,4,5\}$, that bitwise OR is $101_2=5$ and the sum will be $2^{3-1}\cdot 5=20$